# make is calling g++ is always re-compiles even when I do not change the source code

Tags: gcc

I am using make which calls g++ always re-compiles the code, even when I do not change the source code. That happens for all my projects, even for simple ones such as:

```
    [code]
    all: main.cpp
        g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
    [/code]
```

I believe it should compare the date/time on source and object code. Could some help me with this, I am running using GNU toolchain on Ubuntu 12.04

THX

Edit: sorry guys, I do use Makefile, I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simplest Makefile

It was already pointed out that your Makefile is probably wrong. The 'all' target is indeed always built (although it may result in a no-op if it has no commands and all dependencies are already satisfied). All you need in your makefile is this:

```
all: main
```

### Object files

If you expect to have more source file in your build, you should consider creating intermediate object files:

```
all: main
main: main.o
```

### Tweak the build

Make will automatically find the `main.ccp` file and turn it into `main` which is required per the directive above. You can use special make variables to further tweak the compilation, e.g. for debug information inclusion and for warning configuration:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror

all: main
main: main.o
```

### Nitpicking

If you insist on building up the compile rule yourself, you can do it like this:

```
%.o: %.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

CXX: C++ compiler

CPPFLAGS: C preprocessor flags

CXXFLAGS: C++ compiler flags

$@: Target

$<: First dependency

If you don't want to use the standard variables nor pattern matching, you can build up the whole makefile explicitly:

```
all: main
main: main.o
    gcc -o $@ $^
main.o: main.c
    gcc -g -Wall -Werror -o $@ -c $<
```

$^: Use that one if you want to include *all* dependencies, for example if you have multiple `*.o` files to build one binary.

Note: It is a bad idea to write the file names directly into the command as you might forget to update them later.

Comment: `The 'all' target is indeed always rebuild ` wrong. Running `make` the second time gives `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`.

Comment: @legends2k I don't think it's actually wrong but I improved the wording. It's processed, all of its dependencies are processed, and all of its commands are run (none in this case). Feel free to propose a neven better wording.

Comment: in this example: %.o: %.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $  why there is -o option if it only compiles? Also, could you expand this example so it is also build executable. Thanks for the thorough reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
all: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
```

This seems wrong. Why does the rule for `all` has main.cpp as its target? Shouldn't it be something.exe or something.o? Say

```
all: main.exe

main.exe: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe

clean:
    del main.exe
```

Targets are output files and cpp files are source code which should be input to the make system.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will always compile the code. If you want to do conditional compilation (based on file times etc) you will need to use a make system such as Make, CMake, Ant, etc. For the simplest you can set up a small "Makefile" in the directory and use the command "make" to build.

Simple Makefile for compiling "myapp.exe" from "main.cpp", "file1.cpp" and "file2.cpp"

```
myapp.exe: main.o file1.o file2.o
    g++ -o myapp.exe main.o file1.o file2.o
```

(make knows to use .cpp files to build .o files)

But if you also have header files, then you will need to build dependency chains, for which you may want to look into something more sophisticated like automake, cmake, ant, etc.

---- EDIT ----

Based on your updated post, the problem is that you aren't specifying a target, so Make has to assume it needs to recompile. See my example in the above answer.

Comment: I do use make file, sorry for the confusion, I edited my question.

Comment: Edited the answer: The problem is you're using "all" as a target and not specifying an output target. Thus, Make has nothing to check against.

Answer (score 0):

g++ would have to "recompile" in general (what happens if you change the header but not main.cpp?)

If you are concerned about long build times, you should use something like Make (which is designed specifically to avoid recompiling when the source hasn't changed)